Using Social Forward to share individual content blocks
When I add the Social Forwarding functionality to an existing content block in my email, it shares the entire email, not the content block I want to be able to share.
The documentation states "Choose the sections of the email to enable with Social Forward" but I can't figure out how to only allow that specific content block to be shared.
The Share a Content Area using the Editor instructions seem straight forward, but after step 2 I'm not seeing where I can "choose Social Properties."
I assume I'm missing something obvious but can't figure it out.
EDIT: Bumping this up; surely someone has to know the answer to this...
